# Border gradient

Tags: css

Нужна помощь в создании border gradient'a. Пример будет опубликован ниже. Сам гридиент для: input[type="text"]. Ссылка на картинку ниже. Заранее спасибо!
http://plasmon.rghost.ru/58648508/image.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это не градиент, а **box-shadow**.

http://jsfiddle.net/0psh3wp6/

HTML

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Box-shadow" />
```

CSS

```
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

input[type="text"]{
    width: 300px;
    height: 30px;
    padding: 10px 20px;    
    display: block;
    margin: 50px auto;
    background: #FAFAFA;    
    border: 1px solid rgb(82, 168, 236);
    border: 1px solid rgba(82, 168, 236, 0.8);
    outline: 0;
     -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075), 0 0 8px rgba(82, 168, 236, 0.6);
     -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075), 0 0 8px rgba(82, 168, 236, 0.6);
      box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075), 0 0 8px rgba(82, 168, 236, 0.6);
}
input[type="text"]:focus{
    background: #fff;
}
```